# How can I create a smart contract using another smart contract?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, dapps, smart-contract-wallets

I want to create a smart contract which I can link to my website using web3.js and create input fields for creating a contract using the main contract and I can set the fees also which should go inside the main contract for creating a contract.
Please let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Its not straight forward but here is an example from uniswap: [uniswap createpair function](https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-core/blob/4dd59067c76dea4a0e8e4bfdda41877a6b16dedc/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L23)

It boils down to using the evm create2 opcode: [create2](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/cli/2.8/deploying-with-create2)